# Como remover as divs de uma lista de imagens com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei divs usando:

```
 $('.images').find('img').replaceWith(function () {
     return '<div class="resize">' + this.outerHTML + '</div>'
 });
```

**HTML de saída:**

```
<div class="images">

 <div class="resize"><img src="img1.jpg"></div>
 <div class="resize"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>
 <div class="resize"><img src="img3.jpg"></div>

</div>
```

Agora gostaria de reverter para isso, é possível?

```
<div class="images">
   <img src="img1.jpg">
   <img src="img2.jpg">
   <img src="img3.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img').unwrap();
```

Isto deve resultar

Comment: mas daí, vai apagar as imagens, não?

Comment: sim, o remove apaga tudo incluindo os seus descendentes,

Comment: usa antes o unwrap para retirar o elemento pai

Comment: Valeu, funcionou aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/34b9sdpd/

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o script abaixo faça o que você deseja:

```js
 $("#reverter").click(function() {
    $(".resize").each(function(){
        var content = $(this).html();
        $(".images").append(content);
        $(this).remove();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="images">

 <div class="resize"><img src="img1.jpg"></div>
 <div class="resize"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>
 <div class="resize"><img src="img3.jpg"></div>

</div>

<input type="button" name="botao" id="reverter" value="reverter">
```

Observe que ao clicar no botão, as `divs` das imagens serão removidas e o código ficará exatamente assim:

```
<div class="images">
   <img src="img1.jpg">
   <img src="img2.jpg">
   <img src="img3.jpg">
</div>
```